# Xcrun missing, installing Xcode Command Line Tools not fixing issue

Tags: macos, high-sierra, xcode, homebrew

I have a Mid 2015 MacBook Pro running macOS High Sierra 10.13.3.

I tried starting up a new project and none of my commands seem to work.

I always get this error:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), 
missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

Seems pretty straight forward, Xcode Command Line Tools missing. Except installing it seems to not work/have no effect.

I enter: `xcode-select --install`, press install, agree to the agreement, it downloads, installs, gives me a nice `The software was installed` but if I try any command again (like `brew update` or `brew upgrade`); I get the same error. (I tried rebooting, but to no effect).

How do I resolve this issue? All I could find on Google is people saying *Install Xcode Command Line Tools*.

Comment: Does the output of `brew config` outputs a value corresponding to `CLT:` key?

Comment: @NimeshNeema Nope

`HOMEBREW_VERSION: 1.5.14
ORIGIN: (none)
HEAD: (none)
Last commit: never
Core tap ORIGIN: (none)
Core tap HEAD: (none)
Core tap last commit: never
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
CPU: octa-core 64-bit haswell
Homebrew Ruby: 2.3.3 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
Clang: N/A
Git: 2.8.1 => /usr/local/bin/git
Curl: 7.54.0 => /usr/bin/curl
Java: 1.8.0_77
macOS: 10.13.3-x86_64
CLT: N/A
Xcode: N/A
XQuartz: N/A`

Comment: As can be seen from the output, Homebrew doesn't recognise the installation of Xcode and CLT. Have you installed Xcode via DMG or from the Mac App Store?

Comment: I don't have Xcode (never needed it), installed CLT via the terminal as I explained in my original question. As far as I know Xcode isn't necessary for homebrew. Never had it and it always worked fine... Unless it's a new requirement?

Comment: Yes, Xcode isn’t required to install CLT and Homebrew.

Comment: so.. any idea how I can make homebrew recognise my CLT?

Comment: Running `xcode-select —install` is the recommended approach, but you have already tried that. What does the output of `brew doctor` says?

Comment: is it possible to uninstall it and just re-install it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Okay, After a full day of attempts, re-installing homebrew and all... found a solution which I should have tried a lot earlier in all honesty. Leaving it here if anyone else has the same problem in the future:

Doing `xcode-select --install` showed everything as being installed correctly but I just couldn't confirm that anywhere. I downloaded the CLT as a pkg from the apple developer website (https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) and installed it the old fashioned way. CLT is now installed and homebrew is detecting it just fine.

Brew Config now:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 1.5.14
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 7fd6210127f088b6ee8708a1d7f4ec2df3fc5bb4
Last commit: 6 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 1f9ba958e21dce9673b932cfc1f55dd155f0df69
Core tap last commit: 31 hours ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
CPU: octa-core 64-bit haswell
Homebrew Ruby: 2.3.3 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
Clang: 9.1 build 902
Git: 2.8.1 => /usr/local/bin/git
Curl: 7.54.0 => /usr/bin/curl
Java: 1.8.0_77
macOS: 10.13.3-x86_64
CLT: 9.3.0.0.1.1521514116
Xcode: N/A
XQuartz: N/A
```

Thanks Nimesh for helping me!

Comment: i had the same issue - running `xcode-select --install` fixed it for me but installing CLT manually would also do the trick!

Comment: This answer saved my life! After upgrading to catalina, nothing was working for me!

Comment: what does "installed it the old fashioned way." mean?

Comment: what does it mean to "download the CLT"?

Comment: is it possible to uninstall the command line tools and reinstall them from scratch?

Comment: for uninstall and installing again from scratch see my answer which is all in the command line: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/436612/72191

Comment: This answer helped me after upgrading to Ventura MacOS 13.1 as I released git didn't exist on my machine anymore.  Opening XCode and trying to install from there didn't help.  Note that running `xcode-select --install` prompted for command line tools and that's all it did but that's all I needed

Answer (score 22):

I had to check configuration of location as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50093107) to make it work:

> You can just select command line tools from the XCode Preferences show in below screenshot.
>
> You will be prompted for password.
>
> [image]

Comment: It's better to include the key points of the answer here instead of just providing a link.  It's also helpful if you review [How to Answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers that attract views and subsequently, up votes.

Comment: Useful if you have xCode installed (which is not my case; don't use it and can't afford 10GB of storage on something I don't use..) my question was specific to no-xCode installed... Thanks for the answer though, could help others :)

Comment: This was the only answer that worked for me

Comment: This worked for me, when setting up the Glasgow Haskell Compiler! Very easy fix!

Comment: This is it. Thank you very much, I would have never found that.

Comment: Is the solution to install Xcode or what? I don't understand what you did here.

Comment: is it possible to uninstall the command line tools and reinstall them from scratch?

Answer (score 12):

If the above answer doesn't fully fix the problem you can also check `Brew Doctor` mine was also complaining that Xcode.app was in the wrong place and to fix suggested the fix.

`sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app`

My `/Applications` folder had somehow changed from `~/` to `/`

Comment: what is brew doctor?

Comment: is it possible to uninstall the command line tools and reinstall them from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

What I suggest is to uninstall the command line tools (CLT) and re-install them the official way.

So do ([source](https://mac.install.guide/commandlinetools/6.html)):

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

check it uninstalled, you should get an output as follows:

```
xcode-select -p
```

output

```
xcode-select: error: unable to get active developer directory, use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to set one (or see `man xcode-select`)
```

then install the command line tools (CLT) again:

```
xcode-select --install
```

then agree to it and it should download after a couple of minutes. The download should take some time. For me ~13mins.

After that your issues with PyCharm, git, brew and likely other tools will be resolved.

note you should stop getting the error:

```
xcrun: error: unable to load libxcrun (dlopen(/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib, 0x0005): tried: '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib' (no such file)).
```

Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Copying answers from https://github.com/gfx-rs/gfx/issues/2309#issuecomment-506130902

In case anyone else arrives at this issue from a search:

gfx requires both Xcode and the Xcode command line tools. Even if you have the command line tools installed, you still need Xcode.

Xcode is required for the complete macOS SDK (specifically the tools for compiling Metal shaders). The command line tools are required to use the SDK without opening the Xcode app.

You might have installed the command line tools before installing Xcode. For instance, you might have set up Homebrew first. The command line tools are pointing to an incomplete SDK, rather than the one you installed with Xcode.

How to fix

1. Install Xcode from the Apple App Store.
2. Install the command line
   tools with `xcode-select --install`. This might do nothing on your
   machine.
3. If `xcode-select --print-path` prints
   `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`…
4. then run `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`.

Comment: is it possible to uninstall the command line tools and reinstall them from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

I switched to Xcode's Command Line Tools to get it working in my case. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34617930

Comment: What do you mean switch - the only command line tools have always been Xcode

Answer (score -1):

Also ran into this.  Turns out homebrew had installed my Xcode cmd line tools in /usr/bin.  My IntelliJ looks for the cmd line tools at /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/   So what I did was cd into /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ then did a

```
cp /usr/bin/* ./
```

and my cmd line tools were copied in.  After that, IntelliJ had no more complains.

Comment: It's really strange to copy all commands in `/usr/bin/`.