# Git not working on M1 chip after migration

Tags: terminal, mac, homebrew, apple-silicon

I bought a new MacBook Air with the new M1 chip and I migrated my data from my previous intel mac to this. Now when I try to run `git` I get the following error:

```
xcrun: error: unable to load libxcrun (dlopen(/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib, 0x0005): tried: '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib' (no such file)).
```

When I run it using `arch -x86_64 git --version` it works and gives the following:

```
arch -x86_64 git --version                     
git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)
```

Is there any solution to this so I can run `git` alone in the terminal without having to specify the architecture first?

Comment: Did you updated to the latest version of Monterey and reinstall Xcode and the command line tools on the new Mac? I get `git version 2.32.0 (Apple Git-132)` here.

Comment: @nohillside I don't use Xcode so I don't install it and when I try to install the command line tools manually via `xcode-select --install` I get the following: `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`

Comment: You still need to get a newer version then, the one you have seems to be only for Intel.

Comment: @nohillside Do you have any clue how to do so?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321858/xcrun-missing-installing-xcode-command-line-tools-not-fixing-issue might help

Comment: Try this to reinstall the CLT (which will hopefully get you the right architecture.  https://trac.macports.org/wiki/ProblemHotlist#reinstall-clt

Comment: @nohillside You are right.. it really did help thanks

Comment: @MarcWilson: MacPorts' documentation is very good!

Comment: Did the OP do it and did it install the right version?

Comment: uninstall the command line tools and reinstall them: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/436612/72191

Answer (score 2):

Clearly the *best* answer is to get the version of `git` that works with your machine's M1 architecture. That appears to be [installation of the Xcode CLT](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321858/xcrun-missing-installing-xcode-command-line-tools-not-fixing-issue). MacPorts and Homebrew both require CLT, so I don't believe there's a way around that.

However, as an *ad-hoc* solution, you could create an `alias` for your shell that would allow you to run the X86 arch version of `git`. It's a slightly different process for `zsh` vs. `bash`, but details for setting up aliases for both are [covered in this article.](https://wpbeaches.com/make-an-alias-in-bash-or-zsh-shell-in-macos-with-terminal/)

Comment: is it possible to uninstall it and just re-install it?

Comment: seems it is, for that do this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/436612/72191