# Xcode Command Line Tools not installing, missing xcrun

Tags: macos, command-line, install, xcode

I am running Monterey 12.5. My `make` command suddenly stopped working, prompting me to install Command Line Tools, but after installing from the pop-up I get the error

```
xcrun: error: invalid DEVELOPER_DIR path (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer), missing xcrun at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcrun
```

and indeed `xcrun` is missing in that directory. The issue is similar to [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321858/xcrun-missing-installing-xcode-command-line-tools-not-fixing-issue) but downloading the dmg and installing the tools manually does not fix my issue. I've tried all the fixes online like `sudo xcode-select -r` and `sudo xcode-select -switch ...` with restarts all over the place to no avail. Running `xcode-select --install` tells me

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

but of course there are no software updates for this.

I am able to run `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang` (which gets around tools like gcc which I believe just invoke `xcrun` to call `clang`) but nothing seems to be linked as I am met with

```
loop.c:1:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
```

If I run `gcc` from Homebrew, I can run `gcc` with no input files, but as soon as I run `gcc -o loop loop.c` I run into the same `xcrun` error.

In Xcode preferences, Locations/Command Line Tools says Xcode 13.4.1 (13F100) which matches the version of Xcode I have installed.

How can I fix the `xcrun` error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating to Xcode 14.2 the other day seems to have fixed it.

`xcrun` did give the error `"SDK/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk" cannot be located` but creating a symlink with that name to the newest version fixed it for now. All the tools are working as intended.